# Google Maps Static API не возвращает картинку

Tags: google-maps-api, google-maps, карты

Создал на Google Maps Static API учётные запись для ключа API, делаю get-запрос - [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=мой](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) api ключ - в ответ должна прийти картинка с формированной картой, но приходит - [image: скриншот]

Я создал бесплатный аккаунт на этом сервисе, почему не приходит изображение, я не могу разобраться в правилах использования этого ресурса, может там ограничения квот на запросы, или в чём может быть причина?

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблеммы с ключем . Вы или его не верно ввели, или не подвязали банковскую карту или что то в этом роде. проблемма с ключем, так как с моим работает

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.714728,-73.998672&zoom=12&size=400x400&maptype=satellite&key=AIzaSyBNm_E5s9GF0ISJ5vAJIfrx_1s3WboNu_8

Comment: Вот с моим ключем

Comment: И еще, при создании ключа , нужно ставить все галочки Maps Routes Places

Comment: Vlad Miller: а у вас полностью настроенный платежный аккаунт google для биллинга? Вы сканы при регистрации карты отсылали?

Comment: Нет, я не настраивал и не подключал платёжный аккаунт для биллинга, я не смог разобраться в этом, Пользоваться этим API бесплатно, а именно получать изображение карт по get-запросу с параметрамми не получиться, это платный сервис?

Comment: Это условно бесплатный сервис.Бесплатный доступ к 25 000 загрузкам (просмотрам) карт в день, для большинства  сайтов этого более чем достаточно, если лимит привешен тогда, гугл выставит счет. Для этого и привязывают карту.(Раньше такого не было). Вводите данные карты, если чегото опасаетесь , мажете создать виртуальную карту , пройти верификацию , и закрыть ее.Только учтите , что баланс карты должен быть около 2 долларов, гугл их снимет а потом вернет. А без привязки банковской карты никак.

Comment: https://divitheme.space/novyye-kak-poluchit-google-maps-api-key.html

Comment: Никаких сканов не отсылал , просто ввел данные карты , сняли доллар и вернули.Карты с нулевым балансом не подходят, проверено.